# Why are Bose-Einstein Condensates (BECs) named after Bose and Einstein?

Tags: theoretical-physics, einstein, statistical-mechanics

Why are Bose-Einstein Condensates (BECs) named after Bose and Einstein? What did Einstein contribute to BECs?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, there was a paper by Bose, followed by two papers by Einstein, predicting this state of matter.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar What were those papers?

Comment: This article http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~pelster/Vorlesungen/WS1213/delbrueck.pdf by Max Delbrück gives a personal view of the history of the Bose and Einstein papers mentioned in Gerald Edgar's comment (and, of course, gives references to the papers). Although the original papers are in German, they have all been translated and can be found online with little effort.